# Properties value getting Ignored by JSON schema validator

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I am using fge json schema validator 2.2.x version. when i run a basic example of validating JSON Object, I am getting the following warning and the keys are getting ignored.

Sample schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "str": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "str"
  ]
}
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "str1": "str"
}
```

Java code:

```
JsonNode fstabSchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(new File("input/sample.json"));
JsonNode good = JsonLoader.fromFile(new File("input/sample-schema.json"));
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(fstabSchema);
ProcessingReport report = schema.validate(good, true);
System.out.println(report);
```

Ideally the above example should print failed as str is required as per the schema, But it is printing success with the following warning.

```
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ListProcessingReport: success
--- BEGIN MESSAGES ---
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [str]
    level: "warning"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":""}
    domain: "syntax"
    ignored: ["str"]
---  END MESSAGES  ---
```

Tried lots of search about the warning but didn't find any solution / fix. Please correct me, what i am doing wrong?

Note: The above example works well on [online](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Swap the files assigned to the `fstabSchema` and `good` variables. It worked for me. Otherwise the JSON file is used as a schema, and JSON Schema file is validated against it.

Comment: Great. Thanks for pointing out the issue. It works fine now.

Comment: But why they have provided it in reverse. Method clearly say **factory.getJsonSchema**. So it should return schema rather than the JSON to be validated.

Comment: Because a JSON, not a JSON Schema, was assigned to fstabSchema: `JsonNode fstabSchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(new File("input/sample.json"));`, An easy mistake to make.

Comment: Oh my bad! Thanks got it.